# DBNull error - 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web-applications, .net-2.0

Using Visual Studio 2008 and generating .net 2.0 framework with VB.net for a web application.

I encountered a very strange problem currently. After I build a solution and click a link in a web page, I got an error message as following. The same thing happened when I tried to run in debug mode.

```
*************************************** ERROR Message ******************************************************
"An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code"
"Additional information: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "". "
*******************************************************************************************************************
```

The problem part is simply as below in a vb file. The value of `dataview(0)(“name”)` is NULL and `my_name` is a variable string. The strange is thing I didn't change any code in this vb file.  This vb file was built previously and used for a long time ago without any problem. It just suddenly happened today.  I have this syntax all over the program without causing any problem.  I have tried to restore the whole solution back to original but still have the problem.

Can anyone please advise why all the sudden and how to fix?

`If dataview(0)(“name”) =  my_name then …`

Comment: Because all of sudden you have NULL values in the `name` column. If this is never happened before then someone has changed the database to allow the insert of NULL values in that column. (Or the site has never been tested carefully)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually the name column has NULL values long time ago and I am running SQL 2000 which I set the table column property to be "allow null" already. Is there any where in Visual Studion 2008 that I need to change? I am desperate. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to determine NULL value first ..

```
If NOT IsDBNull(dataview(0)(“name”)) Then 
  If dataview(0)(“name”) = my_name then

    'codes here    

  End If
End If
```

Comment: Actually, I have the mentioned problem syntax all over the program and they don't have problem before. If I change it one by one, that will take forever. Could this has something to do with Visual Studio 2008 or microsoft.visualbasic.dll library? Thanks anyway.

Comment: maybe some ACCIDENT occured in your file operation that made NULL value in your DB field .. so you may fix it manually in in your DB

Comment: Actually, the field is allow null already and it does have NULL value before the incident and worked before. Strange. Thanks anyway.